# Laravel 5.4 cascade not working ( also not working One to many relationship ) for creating REST API

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, rest, laravel-5.4

Check My code, I am creating REST API using laravel 5.4 with Mysql using one to many relationship,help me find out the error

### My migrate code table & model  for Accounts (user has many accounts )

```
<?php
 class CreateAccountsTable extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('bank_name');
        $table->string('ac_no');
        $table->timestamps();


    });

    Schema::table('accounts', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('accounts');

    Schema::table('accounts', function($table) {
        $table->dropForeign('accounts_user_id_foreign');
    });
}
```

}

### Accounts Model

```
class Accounts extends Model
 {
       protected $fillable =[
         'bank_name','ac_no'
       ];
   public function useraccounts()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
  }
 }
```

### User Table Migrate code & model User have Many accounts

### Table code

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email',191)->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
}
```

### User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
  public function accounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Accounts');
}
// this is a recommended way to declare event handlers
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($user) { // before delete() method call this
        $user->accounts()->delete();
        // do the rest of the cleanup...
    });
}
}
```

### My controller

```
 // One to many relationship

public function one_to_many(Request $request)
{
    $v = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'bank_name'=>'required',
        'ac_no'=>'required',
        'user_id'=>'required'
    ]);

    $user_id = $request->input('user_id');
    $bankname = $request->input('bank_name');
    $ac_no = $request->input('ac_no');

    if($v->fails())
    {
        $response = [

            'msg' => 'Check your input Error Occur',
            'status' => false,
            'reason' => $v->errors()
        ];

        return response()->json($response, 422);
    }elseif(! User::find($user_id))
    {
        $response = [

            'msg' => 'Give the correct Userid',
            'status' => false,
            'reason' => 'Cant find the user_id from DB'
        ];

        return response()->json($response, 422);
    }

   $user =  User::find($user_id)->id;

    //$get = $user->posts();

    $array = array('bank_name'=>$bankname,'ac_no'=>$ac_no);

    $savepost = Accounts::create($array);


    $savepost->useraccounts()->save($user);

    return $savepost;
}
```

ERROR:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laraapirest`.`accounts`, CONSTRAINT `accounts_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `accounts` (`bank_name`, `ac_no`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (adasdasd, 11111, 2017-02-13 20:07:34, 2017-02-13 20:07:34))



PDOException in Connection.php line 449:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a       child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laraapirest`.`accounts`, CONSTRAINT `accounts_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Comment: Accounts table has an column `user_id` but when call `Account::create` in your controller you don't pass the `user_id` therefore it throws an error, also you need to define the `user_id` as fillable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answers is using associate in relationship for many method because they have collection with that one model and belongsto other model

### Answer is

```
$savepost->useraccounts()->associate($user);
$savepost->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the User ID on this line in your controller:

```
$array = array('bank_name'=>$bankname,'ac_no'=>$ac_no);

$savepost = Accounts::create($array);
```

You need to pass it as `create()` will attempt to write to the database.

Another option would be to initialize the `Account` using the `new` operator, and pass the variables:

```
$array = array('bank_name'=>$bankname,'ac_no'=>$ac_no);

$savepost = new Accounts;
$savepost->bank_name = $bankname
....

$savepost->useraccounts()->save($user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$savepost = Accounts::create($array);` with `$savepost = new Accounts($array)`

and replace `$savepost->useraccounts()->save($user);` with `$user->accounts()->save($savepost);`

Comment: Why? Without an explanation, this doesn't help the OP much.